# CRUD 405 method not allowed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im doing a CREATE for my project(react/laravel) the backend is working fine but when i send the handleSubmit i get this message:
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/alunos/Nametest 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Function:

```
handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ aluno: event.target.value });
}

handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    await axios.post(url + "api/alunos/" + this.state.aluno)
        .then((response) => {
            this.alunos.push({
                nome: this.aluno.nome,
            });
            this.aluno.nome = "";
            this.getUsers();
        });
}
```

HTML

```
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Nome Aluno:
                         <input type="text" name="nome" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
                <button type="submit">Add</button>
            </Form>
```

Comment: What are you sending in data? I cannot see any payload?

Comment: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/alunos/Nametest", im sending "Nametest" in the input

Comment: Does the post api expect any headers like content-type:application/json or text ? Also is not payload then why it is POST API?